# content_panels in StreamBlock StreamField

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I have a few custom StreamField blocks defined. I'd like the option to be able to collapse some properties within the custom blocks much like i can do with a standard page model using content_panels however I don't believe this is supported. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear that this is possible without writing some custom css/js for your admin pages.

There is one work around solution for collapsing one `StreamFieldPanel` inside a standalone `MultiFieldPanel`, however this is not for blocks within the `StreamFieldPanel`.
[Direct link to Comment](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/1336#issuecomment-227770846)

This feature has been requested and it appears it will not be implemented:

- [Issue 1532](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/1532) Explains why this feature does not exist.
- [Issue 1336](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/1336) More explanation from Gasman about why this would add complexity and not really solve the UI problem, but there might be a future related feature in the works.