# Howto customize the editing interface for a subclassed `StructBlock` in a `StreamField`

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I have a wagtail project which utilize the `sites` framework and having a single page as homepage for each `site`. These homepages do not (necessarily) need child pages; their content is build from various streamfield `StructBlock`s.

Each of these `StructBlock`s have a distinct set of fields, but also have some fields in common (e.g. `show_in_navigation`).

In order not to repeat the `show_in_navigation` `BooleanBlock` for each `StructBlock`, I created a `BaseStructBlock` with the common fields and subclassed this for my specific blocks:

```
# models.py
class Homepage(Page):
    body = StreamField(
        BaseStreamBlock(),
    )

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    StreamFieldPanel('body'),
]
```

---

```
# blocks.py
class BaseStructBlock(StructBlock):
    show_in_navigation = BooleanBlock()

class BaseStructBlock(StructBlock):
    show_in_navigation = BooleanBlock()

    def get_form_context(self, value, prefix='', errors=None):
        context = super(BaseStructBlock, self).get_form_context(
            value, prefix=prefix, errors=errors
        )
        # reverse order of fields in OrderedDict, so that the fields from
        # BaseStructBlock appear after the specific fields
        context['children'] = collections.OrderedDict(
            reversed(list(context['children'].items()))
        )
        return context

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class FooBlock(BaseStructBlock):
    # field definitions

class BarBlock(BaseStructBlock):
    # field definitions

class BaseStreamBlock(StreamBlock):
    foo_block = FooBlock()
    bar_block = BarBlock()
```

That works - I get my `show_in_navigation` in all blocks which inherit from `BaseStructBlock` - but I would like to customize the editing interface for these fields:

- <strike>at the moment, all fields from `BaseStructBlock` appear above the fields from the subclassed blocks - I would like to have them displayed below the *specific* fields</strike> - solved, see update in `BaseStructBlock`
- I would be glad to use all these cool panel customizations which are availabe via [`edit_handlers`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/pages/panels.html) and make all my common fields `collapsible`, par example.

Is this possible? All hints greatly appreciated.

PS: I do notice the docs section 
[Custom editing interfaces for StructBlock](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/topics/streamfield.html#custom-editing-interfaces-for-structblock) , but I do not see how this could solve my needs...

PPS: This project:

- Django (2.0.1)
- wagtail (2.0b1)

Comment: I'm not aware of any documented way to reorder those fields. Looking at the documentation you linked to, it looks like the `context` should have a `children` key as an ordered dict, therefore you might be able to mess with that order in `get_form_context`.

Comment: Thanks for this hint - I managed to solve the first issue (reversing the order of fields) and will update my question accordingly.

Comment: It seems that having a panel-like interface inside streamfields is not supported, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355505/content-panels-in-streamblock-streamfield and https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/3942#issuecomment-346815842